# List item "translator" in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am new to prolog and still learning the language.
I can't understand why my code in Prolog is not working.
I am trying to make some kind of translator with lists.
Input: `translate([strings to translate], [dictionary], [translation])`
ex. `translate([m,n], [(m,c), (m,d), (n,e), (c,f)], X)`
Needed output: `X=[c,d,e]`
Actual output: `False`

```
contain(,[]).
contain(X,[X|]).
contain(X,[_|L]) :- contain(X,L).

contain_2(X, [(X, Y) | ], Y).
contain_2(X, [|T], Y) :-
 contain_2(X, T, Y).

tr(XS, L, Y) :-
 contain(Z, XS),
 contain_2(Z, L, Y).

translate(M, N, R) :-
 setof(Y, tr(M, N, Y), R).
```

My code no matter what returns `False`, but I can't find the reason. I tried debugging and it seems like it returns false before entering `setof`. I have used setof before, but maybe I'm missing something. I changed the structure different times, but this version seems to return the least amount of warnings.

Comment: "least amount of warnings" surely you are joking :-) here is what you do: take parts of your program away until you have _no warnings or errors at all_. At this point you can start adding code _while keeping the number of errors and warnings at 0_.

Comment: @TA_intern There is no warnings to this snippet - just returns false. :)

Comment: The first line already: `contain(,[]).` it gives me an error. so maybe you copy pasted your code wrong

Answer (score 0):

Several lines look like they are missing `_`.

I think the main issue is that `contain_2` has no base case for when the list of pairs is empty. It will get to `contain_2(X, [], Y)` find no predicate matching that and fail. e.g.

```
?- trace, contain_2([1,2], [(1,a),(2,b)], [a,b]).

 Call:contain_2([1, 2],[(1,a), (2,b)],[a, b])
 Call:contain_2([1, 2],[(2,b)],[a, b])
 Call:contain_2([1, 2],[],[a, b])
 Fail:contain_2([1, 2],[],[a, b])
```

You need:

```
contain_2(_, [], _).
contain_2(X, [(X, Y) | _], Y).
contain_2(X, [_|T], Y) :-
    contain_2(X, T, Y).
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I still get the same result. I thought maybe the problem is in the "translate", because it fails before "setof" is called.
Now trace returns Fail at the last step too.

Comment: maybe the problem is that X never changes - maybe I should write it as [H|T], but I can't get it to compile correctly.